# Custom Server Control Property Editor using Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am trying to develop a Custom Server Control in Asp.net. The control has the following Properties among others.

1. ConnectionID  - A Connection String Key from Web.Config file
2. DataSource - A Table or SP Name
3. Columns - An ArrayList Consisting of Columns obtained from using the
   above  properties.

Everything was ok until the Columns Prorerty was added. It uses a Custom Collection Editor for Property Editing. The problem is that the getter method for the Columns Property always gives an error.

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is what I am trying to do in my Property getter Method.

```
 ArrayList cols = new ArrayList(); 
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlDataAdapter sDA = new SqlDataAdapter(this.DataSource, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[this.ConnectionID].ConnectionString);

 sDA.Fill(dt); 

 foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) 
 {
      Column col = new Column();
      col.Name = dc.ColumnName;
      col.Caption = dc.ColumnName;
      cols.Add(col); 
 }

return cols;
```

Comment: Can you debug and see exactly which line is causing the error?

Comment: Ror some unknown Reason the Break Point is Not Hitting at that point. However, I have noted that the problem is in using the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings as without which (using Harcoded Connection String) it returns the Right set of Columns. Lty me also add that This Problem only occurs in the Property Editor  Window.

Comment: You can post the solution worked for you as an answer.